# node.js fs how to handle all errors with the same function

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, fs

I am using express to handle http requests, and the `fs` module to read the html, css, javascript, etc files. The problem is, if an error occurs, I want to do the exact same thing every time (log the error to the console, which is being piped to a file).

As far as I know there is no easy way to handle all of these errors with the same function, except by adding something like this to every callback:

```js
err ? handleError(err) : doStuff()
```

Is there any good way to accomplish this?

If not, are there any alternatives (sync is not an option), or is the above the best way?

Comment: Do you need to use `fs` to server files? Express has a way to serve static assets: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @skovy thanks for letting me know, I should probably use that in the future, I do however still want this general error handling for my main pages.

Comment: What `fs` methods are you using?

Comment: @skovy Just `fs.readFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options for abstraction. The first option is like what you outlined:

```
fs.readFile('index.html', (err, data) => {
  err ? handleError(err) : doStuff(data)
});

fs.readFile('style.css', (err, data) => {
  err ? handleError(err) : doStuff(data)
});
```

The next option is to create a different helper method for the callback:

```
const callback = doStuffFn => (err, data) =>
  err ? handleError(err) : doStuffFn(data);


fs.readFile('index.html', callback(doStuff));
fs.readFile('style.css', callback(doStuff));
```

Lastly, you could consider wrapping the entire `readFile` method in a helper method:

```
const loadFile = (file) =>
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) =>
    err ? handleError(err) : doStuffFn(data)
  );


loadFile("index.html")
loadFile("style.css")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like `process.on('uncaughtException')` but the last one works too.